# Boost any usage

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, insert, boost-any

how can I insert my own class objects into ptr_map from boost. The objects are templated so I can't use some static typename in the map. So I did:

```
ptr_map<string, any> someMap;
```

My class inherits the **boost::noncopyable**.

```
someMap.insert("Test", new MyClass<SomeTemplate>());
```

The error is: error: `no matching function for call to ‘boost::ptr_map`.

---

**UPD**:
I'd prefer to make some wrapper and don't use the boost::any. So:

```
class IWrapper { };
class MyClass : public IWrapper { };

ptr_map<string, IWrapper> someMap;
someMap.insert("Test", new MyClass<SomeTemplate>());
```

Why it won't work (the same error)? I could pass the inherited class into parent interface. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far, most of the time problems of this type ought to be solved with a common base class.  This is the case when all of the classes will be used similarly.  Runtime polymorphism.

I have seen legitimate reasons to not allow a common base class.  In this case `boost::variant` will generally server better as there are still methods to treat each item uniformly (a visitor).  Compile time polymorphism.

I have never seen a legitimate use for for `boost::any`.  I'm not saying there isn't one, but it is so rare that I've never encountered it.

---

That said, try this.

```
std::map<std::string,boost::any> someMap;
boost::any insanity = new MyClass<SomeTemplate>;
someMap.insert("Test",insanity);
```

or

```
boost::ptr_map<std::string,boost::any> someMap;
boost::any* ive_lost_it = new boost::any( new MyClass<SomeTemplate> );
someMap.insert("Test", ive_lost_it );
```

Comment: My clas is templated. I've updated the sample. I can't make some base for it (without template).

Comment: Okay, thanks. The way with any should work. But could you look at new  update of code? I tried to realize your first idea.

Answer (score 1):

First you must provide any* to your ptr_map.
Then the key must be an lvalue (due to exception-safety issues).

```
boost::ptr_map<std::string, any> someMap;
any * p = new any(MyClass<Sometype>);
std::string test = "test";
someMap.insert(test, p);
```

--  edit
Same thing if you are using a wrapper class. the key must be an lvalue.

By the way the problem with the wrapper/base class here is that you won't be able to get back to the original type (and you don't have dynamic polymorphism either because of template type).

Comment: lvalue means assignable (and not const). "test" is non-assignable and const, std::string test however is an lvalue.